# What am I doing wrong with this simple If function in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to teach myself to code and have gravitated towards Ruby.
Upon working on if functions I have come across this problem where even if the user input is == to the answer variable it still comes back as false in the if function. It will not come back as true
I can get it to work if it is an Integer, but for some reason it always returns false when having a string. Tried to convert is as well but can not figure it out.

Thank you for any help.

```
puts("For each question select A, B, or C")
puts("What is the capital of Kentucky?")
puts()
puts("A. Louisville") 
puts("B. Frankfort") 
puts("C. Bardstown")
puts()

answer = String("B")

text = gets()
puts()

if text == answer
    puts("correct")
else
    puts("incorrect")
    puts("The correct answer was " + answer + ".")
end
```

Comment: You don't need to use `String` to create a String. Just do `answer = "B"`. Also, Ruby style is not to use `()` when a method takes no arguments. Just use the name of the method; for example, `puts` instead of `puts()`..

Answer (score 2):

There is an additional method you can call when declaring the "text" variable that will solve this.

The method you used preserves a line break at the end when you press enter to submit an answer so it will never actually correspond to the answer. To remove the line break use the "chomp" method.

```
text = gets.chomp
```

Hope this helped. Good luck.

Comment: Nitpicking, but `gets` doesn't _add_ a line break (unlike `puts`). It just _preserves_ the line break that the user entered by pressing the return key.

Comment: Doing text = gets.chop  allowed the code to correctly run. I am not sure why it works, and will be looking into it, but thank you for the time in answering the question for me.

Comment: I didn't explain as well but basically when you type in your answer and press enter, the "gets" method will also store the line break from when you pressed enter as well. the extra "chomp" method removes the line break from the string so that it corresponds to the answer which also has no line break. Good luck coding and welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: @TravisSidebottom you probably end your input by pressing the "return" or "enter" key. But that also produces a character: the [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character `"\n"` so `text` becomes `"B\n"` which is obviously not the same as `"B"`. [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) just removes that trailing newline character, i.e. `"B\n".chomp` returns `"B"`.

Comment: @Stefan That helps clear up and explain how the .chomp command works. Was not aware that pressing "enter" created a new character. I wonder then, why do I not have to use .chomp when working with Integers. would "1\n" not be the same as 1?

Comment: Thank you both for your time in explaining the answer to this question of mine, I am so frustrated with this, I want so badly to learn a language.

Comment: @TravisSidebottom entering 1 (plus return) does result in the string `"1\n"`. But both, `to_i` and `Integer()` ignore the trailing newline.